# how to solve this the crash when running after updating to swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I just updated to Xcode 8 (swift 3). Converted code, etc. No errors. A few build warnings...nothing that should be an issue.

When I run, with my IPHone connected, it crashed with a `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` . It has hardly anything in the trace back other than

```
0_abort_with_payload
5 _dyld_start
```

and the console error is

```
dyld: could not load inserted library '/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib' because no suitable image found.  Did find:


    /Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib: code signature invalid for '/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib'
```

Comment: Checked the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39860708/ios-app-crash-0-abort-with-payload/40261417#40261417

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error since upgrading to xcode 8 (swift 3). The fix, for me,  was to add an entry in info.plist

To add the permission information for the microphone:

1. Open info.plist
2. Add a new key called "Privacy - Microphone Usage Description"
3. Enter a string that describes why the app need microphone access

Comment: Thanks ... this explanation helped too http://useyourloaf.com/blog/privacy-settings-in-ios-10/

Comment: Upvoted !! In my case, it was "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description". Thank you for this answer !! :)

Answer (score 8):

Just restart your iPhone device.

Answer (score 2):

It mainly crash because you have to write some privacy thing in info.plist if you are using hardwares like camera, gallery etc. Check console for details and add everything you are using in info.plist of your app.

Comment: yesterday I was also getting the same problem, First I was getting this error in some code of statusBar, I commented that part of code. Then again I got this error when I tried to use camera, gallery then I got some message in console to add some code in info.plist

Comment: Where do i find the write dat to write into plist? and way does it have to suddenly change like this just because it is a language update

Comment: what is your error. You don't get the error details with the help of @Lion provided link??. Give me some details when you are getting the exception. If you are getting error when you are using camera, gallery etc then go info.plist of app and add one more row and there you will get options in dropdown, go down to privacy and there is lots of differents types of privacy are there. So choose according to thing which you are using. Mainly they want you to notify the people who using your app that app needs to use device data. Give me error details, then I will easily help you.

Comment: Updated my answer with error - really appreciate any help.

Comment: i added motion privacy, camera, location and still same problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and finally figured it out. I created a Framework in Swift 3 that I then added to one of my other projects. This project that I added it to uses both Swift and Objective-C but is originally an Objective-C project.
For some reason the Framework made in Swift 3 was causing my app to crash immediately when running on an iPhone with that exact error. I deleted the Framework and now it is running fine.
Again, not sure why this happens because the Framework was working fine with the app before and works fine on simulators. So I guess it has to do with the Framework being created in the latest XCode with Swift 3. Maybe someone else can clear this up.
Hope this helps someone!